# Как подключить библиотеку cpr для работы с запросами на сайт. C++

Tags: c++, сеть

Я подключил библиотеку, там следующая ошибка:
1>C:\Users\User\Downloads\cpr-master\cpr-master\include\cpr\bearer.h(4,10): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: curl/curlver.h: No such file or directory,
как исправить ошибку?